# asp.net controls not in correct position

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, css-position

I have a sidebar div that I have given a fixed position so that as the page scrolls it is always visible. Just to make things interesting the sidebar's position is set by some javascript code to deal with lower screen resolutions and problems with it ending up in the wrong position.

That is all working nicely, however it appears that the controls on the div don't move when it gets repositioned so you can't click on them. They appear in the correct position they just don't actually do anything.

I'm sure I've read a solution for this on here but can't track it down.

Here is the CSS for the sidebar:

```
.mainsidebar
{
   display:inline-block;
   width:35.5%;
   float:left;   
   padding: 0px 0px;
   margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
   min-height: 480px;
   position: fixed;
   font-size: 9pt;
   left: 0px;
   overflow:auto;
   background-color: #4b6c9e;
   border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

and the javascript that sets it's position:

```
var elementStyle1 = document.getElementById("mainSideBar");
elementStyle1.style.top = "23.2%";
```

I tried doing the same thing with the asp control but can't get any result.

Ok sorry - you can ignore this. I thought it was the problem I mentioned above as I was sure I had read a solution describing a similar situation.

It actually was the z-index of the controls that was the problem - once I set the div to have a lower z-index than the controls then I was able to click on them.

Comment: Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net example? And what do you mean by the sidebar controls don't 'do anything'. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Post your edit in a seperate answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the ID of the ASP.NET server control is "mainSideBar". Then your javascript code will be

```
var elementStyle1 = document.getElementById("<%=mainSideBar.ClientID%>");
```